# MongoDB - addToSet/push only on upsert

Tags: mongodb, mongoskin

I would like to add a subdocument to an array if it doesn't already exist and then return the newly added subdocument (or at least the array of subdocuments) within one query. Here is an example document structure:

```
{
    "name": "John Smith",
    "folders": [
        {
            "folderName": "Breweries"
            "updatedAt": 1450210046338,
            "checkins": [
                {
                    "facebookID": "123",
                    "checkinID": "3480809",
                    "addedOn": 1450210046338
                },
                {
                    "facebookID": "234",
                    "checkinID": "345254",
                    "addedOn": 1450210046339
                }
            ],
        },
        {
            "folderName": "Food"
            "updatedAt": 1450210160277,
            "checkins": [
                {
                    "facebookID": "432",
                    "checkinID": "123545426",
                    "addedOn": 1450210160277
                }
            ],
        }
    ],
}
```

The nested query below checks to see if the new folder's name already exists in the folders array. If it doesn't already exist, it adds the new folder to the folders array:

(using mongoskin here)

```
mongodb.collection('users').findOne(
    {facebookID: facebookID, 'folders.folderName': folderName},
    function (err, result) {
      if (err) {
        deferred.reject(err);
      } else if (result !== null) {
        deferred.reject(new Error('Folder name already taken'));
      } else {
            mongodb.collection('users').findOne(
    {facebookID: facebookID, 'folders.folderName': folderName},
    function (err, result) {
      if (err) {
        deferred.reject(err);
      } else if (result !== null) {
        deferred.reject(new Error('Folder name already taken'));
      } else {
        mongodb.collection('users').findAndModify(
            {facebookID: facebookID},
            [],
            {$addToSet: {folders: newFolder}},
            {fields:{'folders': 1}, new: true},
            function (err, result) {
              if (err) {
                deferred.reject(err);
              } else {
                deferred.resolve(result);
              }
            });
      }
    });
```

It seems like you should be able to do this in one query - but I couldn't find a way to achieve $setOnInsert functionality with array operators ($addToSet/$push).

Comment: Well an "upsert" result would mean there was no such matching document and therefore you can just create a single element array directly within `$setOnInsert`. i.e `"folders": [newFolder]`. Of course you need to be wary on upserts that you don't test for the array entry itself. Otherwise an upsert would be attempted when all you really want is to add to the array. But you are not doing that here.

Comment: Right, I basically want something like a $addToSetOnInsert - kind of like this except this isn't possible:     db.users.findAndModify({
  query: {facebookID: '123', 'folders.folderName': 'Breweries'},
  sort: [],
  update: {$setOnInsert: {$addToSet: {folders: newFolder}}},
  new: true,
  upsert:true
});

Comment: No. Understand that you are just initializing a brand new array. So just notate it that way as demonstrated above. You don't need the `$addToSet` within the `$setOnInsert`. Or otherwise just use both `$setOnInsert` and `$addToSet` as top level operators of the update statement. You can do that you know.

Comment: I don't want to set folders to an empty array if a folder is not found because that would erase the existing folders. I just want to add the new folder to the array if it's not already in there.